# OctoberCMS RecordFinder Create Record

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend

Is it possible to create a new record using the Record Finder? Or if there are other form widget that's built for this feature?

For example, in a Department, there are Officers.

If an officer already exists in the database, the user can just select the officer to be added to that department.

However, if the user intends to assign an officer to a department which does not yet exist in the database, there would be a form that will automatically create the officer and then assign it to the department.

Is this possible? Currently, I am using RecordFinder with Repeater, since the relationship is *Many to Many*. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"if there are other form widget that's built for this feature" - **yes** fortunately `october CMS` is having `Relation Manager` dedicated to this job.

you can combine `form` + `Relation behavior` which will give you functionality which you required.

> **I highly recommend** watch this **video tutorial** from `auther` it will solve your problem surely.

**https://octobercms.com/support/article/ob-11**

for more confrontational help you can check its api here : **https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/relations**

if you still face any difficulties please comment.

Comment: hi thank you for your effort! i will check this out, and will accept this answer if it indeed helped me.

Comment: sure, just check out video tut. it will surely help you out.

Comment: hi, thank you, the video link you've sent was magical! cheers!

Comment: glad it helped you :)

Comment: Hi @HardikSatasiya ,I read your comment but could not figure out how to apply this to my system. How do I put a "Create Record" button in this RecordFinder? 
 My Print: http://prntscr.com/n9psut

Comment: you can not add button to finder window, but you can add `add button` next to where from you are opening this finder window